# How to connect to the remote mongodb pod running in a kubernetes cluster without its IP using mongo client

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes

I got several replicas of mongodb pods into my cluster. And got a bastion server through which I can connect to each mongodb pod running in a private subnet. I can do that by mongodb pod IP into the connection string.

```
mongodb://username:password@xx.xxx.xxx.112:27017/
```

But I want to connect to the database using a pod name / service name instead of a dynamic pod IP which gets changed every time I recreate the pod. Using the pod default DNS with service name doesn't work in this case ( e.g. mongodb-0.mongo.default.svc.cluster.local)

Any idea how to connect to the mongodb pods using mongo client without using their IPs?

Comment: I can do that by using `kubectl port-forward` locally, but that is not what I want. I want to provide a way for other users to connect to the mongodb pods without kubectl or pod IPs.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/916076/how-to-expose-and-access-mongodb-ports-in-kubernetes

Comment: or using ingress controller supporting TCP: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57623894/how-access-mongodb-in-kubernetes-from-outside-the-cluster